# What is the correct pattern for terminating a task chain due to an exception

Tags: c#, exception, task

The code I have looks like this:

```
var doubleAuthenticateTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => presenter.Authenticate())
.ContinueWith(prev =>
{
  if(prev.IsFaulted) throw prev.Exception;
  // Do something
})
.ContinueWith(prev =>
{
  if(prev.IsFaulted) throw prev.Exception;
  // Do something else
})
```

It seem cumbersome however to have to rethrow the exception from the previous task in order to have it bubble to the top of the chain. Is this the correct pattern, or is there a better one?

I also tried returning a new `Task` using `Task.FromException`, but that also continues to the next task in the chain.

I guess I am looking for a way to indicate that any exception thrown in any of the tasks in the chain should terminate the chain and throw the exception up the chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion` to the 2nd argument of `ContinueWith`.

If you are using C# 5+, you can convert your code to `async`/`await` to structure your code without resorting to `ContinueWith`.